# How do I execute a batch command on multiple files if they're in a different directory than the batch?

Tags: batch-file, windows-8, directory

Im using a batch file to hide files inside a folder by using the code

```
    for /r %%i in (*) do attrib +s +h
```

This works on all files that are in the same direcrory as the bacth file. But I want to run the batch from the desktop and hide files in a folder placed elsewhere, how do i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set system and hidden attribute on all files of a folder and all its subfolders use

```
@echo off
for /R "C:\Temp\Test" %%i in (*) do attrib +s +h "%%i"
```

That is clearly explained in help of command [for](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx) which you can read also offline by opening a command prompt window and enter `help for` or `for /?`.

`"C:\Temp\Test"` is the full path to folder which you have to replace in the code above.